# How to configure .htaccess to redirect .../subpathURL to a specific file (pdf)

Tags: apache, codeigniter, .htaccess

*it's the first time I ask my own question on StackOverflow. I usually find all the help and answers I need in existing topics but here I just can't find any solution for my problem.*

I have a website hosted on **somedomain.com**, my client is currently proposing some prize-winning contest and he wants to host the terms & conditions PDF file on the website. 
This PDF file should be accesible with **somedomain.com/jeu-concours** URL.

Here's my server www/ folder :

### [image]

I do have a **'jeu-concours' folder with the xxxx.pdf file in my root www folder** and I have tried every thing I found on forums to set-up my .htaccess but nothing works..

### [image: See on Imgur]

*Either somedomain.com/jeu-concours displays as file's listing, if I use -Indexes options I can't reach the path, ifI use 301 redirects I get infinite loops, if I use RewriteRule nothing seems happend, etc..*

I am a young computing science engineer and I always get to solve my problems alone but I really have troubles understanding and mastering apache configuration and htaccess management..

---

**Short version :**

I currently have this when I go to **somedomain.com/jeu-concours** :

### [image: See on Imgur]

and instead of this file listing I want to be on my *Reglement-jeu-TAS.pdf* file.
I don't know if I should use RewriteRule, or Redirect or anything else, and I don't know which .htaccess I should modify to make this works...

Thanks for helping guys, I'm quite ashamed to ask such a basic question but I am struggling and I can't afford to spend more time trying things!
Have a nice day :)

Comment: Just add `Rewriterule ^jeu-concours/?$ /jeu-concours/Reglement-jeu-TAS.pdf [L]` to .haccess in your www/ folder

Comment: Hi Dusan, thanks for your answer ! Unfortunately and I don't know why but this ain't working ! And when I say it's not working I really mean "nothing happend, nothing changed, no redirection or URL rewritting were made" so its quite a strange behaviour...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paste the following code at the top of .htaccess file in somedomain.com/jeu-concours directory.

```
#Alternate default index page
DirectoryIndex sample.pdf
```

Comment: This is working fine ! This is simply but it does exactly what I was looking for ! Thank you very much !